# How to transform an Observable<T> into Map<Observable<T>, List<X>> in RxJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

Started working on an ongoing Angular 2 Project and the first bump I have ran into is Observable. Starting to get good understanding of FP but cant wrap my head around observables in Rxjs.

For a given Observable `item$`. I want to get a list of child items for each value in item$ and then return back a new observable containing

```
Map<item, List<ChildItems>>
```

NOTE: I have a function that returns a list of child items give a parent id

What operator do I need to use to achieve this?

Comment: Assuming the `item$` observable completes: `item$.reduce((map, item) => { map.set(item, getChildren(item)); return map; }, new Map<Item, List<ChildItem>>())`

Comment: Also, the question's title is not consistent with the question itself.

Comment: I get an error on new Map<Item, List<ChildItem>>() . Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword. Also I am so new to this RxJS wasnt sure how to word the question properly.. any tips?

Comment: If you are referring to something other than [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), you will have to include it in your question. And your title refers to a different type to that specifed in your question. That is, the `Map` in your title has an `Observable` in it - which makes no sense, anyway.

Comment: Not sure if this is better or worse than using reduce: item$.toArray()
  .map(items => new Map(items.map(item => [item, getChildren(item)] )))